# What is the meaning of this code in service now?

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I am usin My requests widget in Server Now.
There is this line of code.

```
    var notClosedResolved = 'stateNOT IN6,7';
    var closedResolved = 'stateIN6,7';
```

What that means?

Plase help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Both [variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) are [assigned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) values. That's all I'm pretty sure

Comment: What those string values mean depends on the context in which they're used, which isn't specified.

Comment: Those are - most probably - fragments of an SQL query. You can see this to get an idea on how they are used in ServiceNow: https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=f4c9687bdb427fc02e8c2183ca961940

Answer (score 1):

It's an encoded query. State 6/7 by default are the numeric values of the states stored within ServiceNow.

So 'Resolved' and 'Closed' are the "Display" values (what the end user sees) and 6/7 are the numeric value behind those display values, to allow for easier accessibility when developing.

Effectively, the `notClosedResolved/closedResolved` indicate that they'll be used when doing some form of query.

For example:

```
//The two variables storing the encoded queries.

var notClosedResolved = 'stateNOT IN6,7';;
var closedResolved = 'stateIN6, 7';

//The query being added to the GlideRecord, then queried.
var gr = new GlideRecord('incident');
gr.addEncodedQuery(notClosedResolved);
gr.query();

//If any tickets matching the query (Not closed or resolved) exist, then do whatever is in the while and update the record
while(gr.next()){
    gr.short_description = 'Example - All non-closed/resolved incidents';
    gr.update();
}

//The query being added to the GlideRecord, then queried.
var gr = new GlideRecord('incident');
gr.addEncodedQuery(closedResolved);
gr.query();

//If any tickets matching the query (Closed or resolved) exist, then do whatever is in the while and update the record
while(gr.next()){
    gr.short_description = 'Example - All closed/resolved incidents';
    gr.update();
}
```